# How to fix 'WebDriver' object has no attribute 'find element by CSS selector'?

Tags: python, webdriver

I am using callow on a sandbox. I get these errors:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\Users\Joe\callow\callow.py", line 163, in <module>
    wizard()
  File "C:\Users\Joe\callow\callow.py", line 93, in wizard
    brutes(username, username_selector, password_selector, submit_selector, pass_list, website)
  File "C:\Users\Joe\callow\callow.py", line 119, in brutes
    Sel_user = browser.find_element_by_css_selector(username_selector) # Finds Selector
AttributeError: 'WebDriver' object has no attribute 'find_element_by_css_selector'
```

Error originated from:

```
try:
        Sel_user = browser.find.element_by_css_selector(username_selector) # Finds Selector
    except selenium.common.exceptions.NoSuchElementException:
        print((color.RED + '\n[!]'+ color.CWHITE + ' Username feild selector is invalid.'))
        sys.stdout.flush()
        exit()
    try:
        Sel_pas = browser.find_element_by_css_selector(password_selector) # Finds Selector
    except selenium.common.exceptions.NoSuchElementException:
        print((color.RED + '\n[!]'+ color.CWHITE + ' Password feild selector is invalid.'))
        sys.stdout.flush()
        exit()
    try:
        enter = browser.find.element_by_css_selector(submit_selector) # Finds Selector
    except selenium.common.exceptions.NoSuchElementException:
        print((color.RED + '\n[!]'+ color.CWHITE + ' Login button selector is invalid.'))
        sys.stdout.flush()
        exit()
```

How can I fix this?

Answer (score 2):

Since it mentions WebDriver, I'm assuming this is to do with Selenium? `find_element_by_css_selector` is deprecated, and if you were to use an IDE like PyCharm, it would tell you:

> find_element_by_css_selector is deprecated. Please use
> find_element(by=By.CSS_SELECTOR, value=css_selector) instead

So instead of using `find_element_by_css_selector`, consider using:

```
Sel_user = browser.findElement(By.CSS_SELECTOR, username_selector)
```

Refer to the official documentation for more information: https://selenium-python.readthedocs.io/locating-elements.html#locating-elements-by-css-selectors.

Comment: For anybody reading this, the correct syntax for python is the following:
`browser.find_element(By.CSS_SELECTOR, username_selector)`

Answer (score 1):

Please don't forget to import the By object to access the CSS_SELECTOR property. I had to import the following to automate tasks in the Chrome browser.

```
from selenium import webdriver
from selenium.webdriver.chrome.service import Service
from selenium.webdriver.chrome.options import Options
from webdriver_manager.chrome import ChromeDriverManager
from selenium.webdriver.common.by import By

options = Options()
# options.add_experimental_option("detach", True)

driver = webdriver.Chrome(
    service=Service(ChromeDriverManager().install()),
     options=options
     )

driver.get("https://www.python.org/")
driver.maximize_window()

input = driver.find_element(By.CSS_SELECTOR,".documentation-widget p")

print(input)

driver.close()
driver.quit()
```

Comment: Dear god! Can there be more complexity?