# Selenium testing nonetype from click fuction of python

Tags: python, selenium-webdriver, nonetype

Have tried to change many things. but can't run it

```
import pytest
from selenium import webdriver
import time
 
from selenium.webdriver.common.by import By
from selenium.webdriver.support.wait import WebDriverWait
from selenium.webdriver.support import expected_conditions as EC
from utilities.BaseClass import BaseClass
 
class TestOne(BaseClass):
    def test_e2e(self):
        self.driver.find_element_by_css_selector("a[href*='shop']").click()
        cards = self.driver.find_elements_by_css_selector(".card-title a")
        i = -1
        for card in cards:
            i = i + 1
            cardText = card.text
            print(cardText)
            if cardText == "Blackberry":
                self.driver.find_elements_by_css_selector(".card-footer button")[i].click()
        self.driver.find_element_by_css_selector("a[class*='btn-primary']").click()
 
        self.driver.find_element_by_css_xpath("//button[@class='btn btn-success']").click()
        self.driver.find_element_by_id("country").send_keys("ind")
 
        element = WebDriverWait(self.driver, 10).until(EC.presence_of_element_located((By.LINK_TEXT, "India")))
        self.verifyLinkPresence("India")
 
        self.driver.find_element_by_link_text("India").click()
        self.driver.find_element_by_xpath("//div[@class='checkbox checkbox-primary']").click()
        self.driver.find_element_by_css_selector("[type='submit']").click()
        textMatch = self.driver.find_element_by_css_selector("[class*='alert-success']").text
 
        assert ("Success! Thank you!" in textMatch)
```

error this run from CMD

```
  def test_e2e(self):
>       self.driver.find_element_by_css_selector("a[href*='shop']").click()
E       AttributeError: 'NoneType' object has no attribute 'click'
```

and error this run on pycharm

```
    def test_e2e(self):
>       self.driver.find_element_by_css_selector("a[href*='shop']").click()
E       AttributeError: 'WebDriver' object has no attribute 'find_element_by_css_selector'
```

I just learned this recently and am curious and want to fix this kind of error since selenium can use new syntax but I can't run it.

Comment: You can try these 2 solutions. [no attribute 'click'](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/54498343/how-to-fix-attributeerror-nonetype-object-has-no-attribute-click) and
[has no attribute 'find_element_by_css_selector'](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/72836613/how-to-fix-webdriver-object-has-no-attribute-find-element-by-css-selector)